# Could not autowire. No beans of '' type found

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Не получается заавтовайрить сервис. Посдкажите куда смотреть.
Не автовайрится MongoDetailsService в Security configuration.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private MongoDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

```
import com.example.bookStore.entity.Users;
import com.example.bookStore.repo.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class MongoDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = repository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserNotFound");
        }
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"));

        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
}
```

Comment: выложите полный текст ошибки, вроде как должно все работать. Во всяком случае можете попробовать в `SecurityConfiguration  userDetailsService`, объявить как  `UserDetailsService`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите название бина @Component("userDetailsService")в классе MongoDetailsService:

```
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class MongoDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = repository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserNotFound");
        }
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"));

        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
}
```

Comment: помогло. Не заметил, что у меня два мейн класса, может в этом была проблема, но ошибки в логе небыло